# "Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject." when binding Background

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I want to change a label and background of a datagrid inside a Backgroundworker.
I have Grid like this :

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="499" Margin="96,170,810,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="486" Background="{Binding aBackGround}">
    <Label Content="212" FontSize="100"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-4.395,-11.154" Margin="173,22,0,0" Height="123" Width="178"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding aPace}" FontSize="65"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="23,202,0,0" Height="84" Width="255"/>
</Grid>
```

In code behind I have aBackGround and aPace like this:

```
private Brush _aBackGround;
private string _apace;

public Brush aBackGround
{
    get { return _aBackGround; }
    set
    {
        _aBackGround= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.aBackGround);    
    }
}

public string aPace
{
    get { return _apace; }
    set
    {
        _apace = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.aPace);
    }
}
```

I can see the result of aPace correctly but a second later I get

> Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject

exception. Can you tell me how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Where are you using background thread? Posted code seems completely fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whatever code is directly accessing your UI, you can only run on the UI thread.
Use a dispatcher to run it there, e.g.:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    // the code that's accessing UI properties
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Either move your value assignment to backgroundworker completed event

or

use invoke when you assign the value in the backgroundWorker do work

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => 
{
   this.aPace = "test";
}));
```